Get Error Trying to after compile Moodle Android App The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.", source: https://192.168.1.186:8100/
I am Trying To Build A Customized Moodle Android For My Collage Project I used the Guide from Moodle and successfully complied and installed it on my emu but it stays at moodle logo nothing happened
Emu Screen Shot
My logcat For Moodle
`https://pastebin.com/zDuPieEh`

is there anything i missed if what i nned to change i used moodle latest version 4.3 where i need to add my collage site for moodle app
